# Amp-sidebar: Does it absolutely have to be the child of the body? Why?

Tags: html, amp-html

Why does `<amp-sidebar>` HAVE to be the direct child of the body?

I am in a situation where, in terms of code structure, it would be much easier for me to include `<amp-sidebar>` within a `<div>`. I want it to behave exactly like `<amp-sidebar>`, but I simply don't have any easy way to place an element as the direct child of a `<body>`.

I was especially confused when I saw that this [amp-by-example page](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-sidebar/#development=1) does not pass the AMP validator.

Could someone please illuminate me? I thought about opening an issue on github, but I'm not sure if there's a bug.

Answer (score 2):

According to a lead dev of the AMP project, the requirement that `<amp-sidebar>` is child of `<body>` is due to a Safari bug with `position:fixed`. Link to [tweet](https://twitter.com/cramforce/status/783352472014233600).

Comment: I've filed a Github issue against AMP By Example to track and eventually fix this: https://github.com/ampproject/amp-by-example/issues/406

Comment: by modifying the content of menu inside the `amp-sidebar`, I prefer use button `amp-startbtn` to be placed wherever I wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with server side rendering, one possible workaround is to parse the rendered html string and place the sidebar tag as a direct child of body. I have not tried this at scale yet:

```
function fixAmpSidebars(strHtml) {
    let sidebarBegin = 0, sidebarEnd = 0
    const sidebars = []
    do {
        sidebarBegin = strHtml.indexOf('<amp-sidebar', sidebarBegin)
        if (sidebarBegin !== -1) {
            sidebarEnd = strHtml.indexOf('</amp-sidebar>', sidebarBegin) + 14
            sidebars.push(strHtml.slice(sidebarBegin, sidebarEnd))
            strHtml = strHtml.slice(0, sidebarBegin) + strHtml.slice(sidebarEnd)
        }
    } while (sidebarBegin !== -1)
    if (sidebars.length) {
        strHtml = strHtml + sidebars.join('')
    }

    return strHtml
}
```